# WebStorm can't find npm although it is installed via nvm

Tags: npm, ide, webstorm, nvm

WebStorm can't find npm although it is installed via nvm.

[image: WebStorm Preferences showing npm in red]

---

**EDIT:** As I found the answer myself I will post below, hoping that others find this helpful as well.

Answer (score 0):

As I had installed node via multiple ways, e.g. via homebrew AND nvm, the trick is to select the node version that you used to install npm with. In my case that is nvm.

Different node installations:
[image: Different node installations]

nvm selected as node interpreter, offering the npm option:
[image: nvm selected as node interpreter, offering the npm option]